# simulate gyroscope, accelerometer, magnetometer, and GPS?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi
I'm working on project for localization of cars, and I use accelerometer, gyroscope and GPS, (perhaps I will need magnetometer)
I need to know if your simulator can be used in my case (before reading all the documentation) and I prepared this list of questions (according to answers, I will decide to use it or not ) :
can it

1. Simulate gyroscope, accelerometer, magnetometer, and GPS ?
2. Simulate the sensor errors ? can I choose the error's variance ?
3. work with C language ?
4. Can I make scenarios ( for 2 ~ 5 minutes )?
5. from where I can read the simulated output ? socket (TCP/IP protocol) or files like in /dev/*  ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8338/simulate-gyroscope,-accelerometer,-magnetometer,-and-gps-?/) by [user](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1159/user/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-03-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asdfjkl](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2608/asdfjkl/) on 2016-05-26**:
Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

1. Gazebo has IMU, Camera (2d & 3d), magnetometer, GPS, and many more sensors.
2. You can add noise to many of the sensors. Gaussian noise is built into gazebo, but you can extend this functionality.
3. The API uses c++
4. There is no limit on the size of an environment, or the amount of time you want to run simulation.
5. Data is available via TCP/IP, through a library interface, and you can also write custom plugins to handle other cases.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2016-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1